# Help getting JWT Auth working - gettin unsupported_grant_type no matter what I try

Tags: rest-api, jwt

Every example I have found is working against login.salesforce.com or test.saleforce.com, but I don't have access to either of those for my particular project, yet?

I am working in developer sandbox trying to get this code to work as a POC.

What I am noticing is that I get the grant_not_supported error no matter what I try.

My .env file looks like this

```
SF_CONSUMER_KEY=XXXXXXX
SF_CONSUMER_SECRET=XXXXXX
SF_USERNAME=digidigo@empathetic-impala-524fmv.com
SF_DOMAIN=https://empathetic-impala-524fmv-dev-ed.trailblaze.lightning.force.com
```

My code looks like this, modified from a gist online [here](https://gist.github.com/booleangate/30d345ecf0617db0ea19c54c7a44d06f):

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from datetime import datetime
import jwt
import time
import requests
import os

load_dotenv()

# *** Update these values to match your configuration ***
KEY_FILE = 'salesforce.key'
ISSUER = os.environ.get("SF_CONSUMER_KEY")
SUBJECT = os.environ.get("SF_USERNAME")
# *******************************************************

DOMAIN = os.environ.get("SF_DOMAIN")

print('Loading private key...')
with open(KEY_FILE) as fd:
    private_key = fd.read()

print('Generating signed JWT assertion...')
claim = {
    'iss': ISSUER,
    'exp': int(time.time()) + 300,
    'aud': DOMAIN,
    'sub': SUBJECT,
}

print(claim)
assertion = jwt.encode(claim, private_key, algorithm='RS256', headers={'alg':'RS256'})
headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
print('Making OAuth request...')
r = requests.post('{}/services/oauth2/token'.format(DOMAIN), data = {
    'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    'assertion': assertion,
}, headers=headers)

print('Status:', r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

The error looks like this:

```
{'error': 'unsupported_grant_type', 'error_description': 'grant type not supported'}
```

Comment: After doing some reading, it appears that a trailhead playground org is just another variation of a Developer Edition org. In that case, you can use `https://login.salesforce.com` for the domain instead of your unique partitioned domain. So that would be the first thing to try. If you can intercept the request you're making in python to double check the grant type, that'd be good to do too. Also, it's worth trying to go through one of the interactive flows in your browser (or through postman) to see if that works first (because you will pretty much need to use the web-server flow once first).

Comment: And one of the first resources I found with going through the web-server flow with postman is https://www.mikearthur.net/salesforce-oauth-2-0-web-server-flow-authorisation-with-postman (no affiliation).